# iOS remove overlay only when I through the region

Tags: ios

I created many overlays in mapView with this code:

```
MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:userLocation.coordinate radius:1000];
[mapView addOverlay:circle];
```

I would like to remove one by one only when I execute methode:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

My problem is: when I'm coming out of a region, do not know what I went through overlay.
Any idea how I can remove those?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to monitor the regions corresponding to your circles.

Create your `CLRegion`:

`- (id)initCircularRegionWithCenter:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)center radius:(CLLocationDistance)radius identifier:(NSString *)identifier`

Monitor with `CLLocationManager`:

`- (void)startMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region`

Which will send events to your listener, so you can add/remove the overlays when you receive the events:

`- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region`

`- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region`

Probably the easiest way for you will be to store the relationship between `MKCircle` objects and the corresponding `CLRegion` objects, so you can update your map appropriately.